# How to setup original icon by QstandardItem?

Tags: python, pyside2

First, I use Pyside2, I want the QListView to see icons in the default Windows, such as the QFilesystemModel.
The reason why QFilesystemModel is not available is because it wants to show items in folders across multiple paths.
We achieved the goal using the appendRow feature of QStandardItem.
However, Windows' default folders, files, and icons cannot be imported into seticon.

How to set the icon to look like it in Windows with QStandardItem

It's my code.

```
class CustomListView(QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setup_model(self, paths):
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()

        for path in paths:
            path = os.listdir(path)
            
            for file in path:
                item = QStandardItem(file)
                self.model.appendRow(item)

        self.setModel(self.model)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [`QFileIconProvider`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileiconprovider.html) that returns an icon based on the [`QFileInfo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html) associated with the file or folder.

```py
import os

from PySide2.QtCore import QFileInfo
from PySide2.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileIconProvider, QListView


class CustomListView(QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.icon_provider = QFileIconProvider()

    def setup_model(self, paths):
        self.model.clear()
        for path in paths:
            dirs = os.listdir(path)
            for name in dirs:
                filename = os.path.join(path, name)
                icon = self.icon_provider.icon(QFileInfo(filename))
                item = QStandardItem(name)
                item.setIcon(icon)
                self.model.appendRow(item)


def main():
    app = QApplication()
    view = CustomListView()
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    view.setup_model(["/home/user/", "/home/user/Pictures"])

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helped.